# How to convert conversationIndex read using ews to some sortable string value?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I read that outlook uses conversationindex to show the hierarchy of emails in a conversation. I am trying to implement the same thing in my application. For this i am trying to get the conversationIndex to implement a sorting functionality on the value(or value of particular field) of conversationIndex. The problem is, i am not being able to convert conversationindex to some sortable string value??